# How to override java public class method in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, overriding

I need to redefine/override method from java public class in Kotlin class:

```
// Java
public class BaseOne {
    public static void m1() {}
}

// Kotlin
class BaseTwo : BaseOne() {
        override fun m1() {}
}
```

but get an error: `m1 overrides nothing`.

If I remove `override` annotation I get `Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature`.

In java this works fine, but not in Kotlin :(

UPD: working java code

```
public class BaseTree extends BaseOne {
    public static void m1() {}
}
```

**UPD2** "Curiouser and curiouser!" (с)

I have next code:

```
// Java class
public class BaseOne {
    public static void m1() {
        System.out.println("BaseOne");
    }
}

// Kotlin class
class BaseTwo : BaseOne() {
        companion object {
                fun m1() {
                        println("BaseTwo")
                }
        }
}

// Java class
public class BaseThree extends BaseOne {
    public static void m1() {
        System.out.println("BaseThree");
    }
}
```

When I run this code from Java,

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseOne.m1();
        BaseThree.m1();
        BaseTwo.m1();
    }
}
```

I receive:

```
BaseOne
BaseThree
BaseOne
```

As you see - override/redefine/"hide" doesn't work

But if I run it from Kotlin's `main`

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        BaseOne.m1()
        BaseThree.m1()
        BaseTwo.m1()
}
```

all works as intended:

```
BaseOne
BaseThree
BaseTwo
```

My additional question is - How to write code with equal behaviour? Is there a docs about it?

Comment: Are you sure m1 is supposed to be static in `BaseOne`?

Comment: @kabuko, yep. This case works fine in java

Comment: That's not overriding it. You're just hiding the base implementation.

Comment: @kabuko, ok. is there equal code for kotlin?

Comment: It might be better to explain what you're trying to achieve. This is a code smell. Why do you need it to be static? If it really does, then why do you need to hide it in `BaseTwo`? How are you calling this function? Most likely you would be better served by making it not static.

Comment: @kabuko, I can't remove `static`. It's not my code. I want to rewrite one intellij plugin on Kotlin. There is one significant place, where parser are hooked and create instance of PsiBuilder. (https://github.com/kandeshvari/idea-nim/blob/master/src/org/dmitrigb/ideanim/parser/ParserUtil.java#L160). It overrides this https://github.com/JetBrains/Grammar-Kit/blob/master/src/org/intellij/grammar/parser/GeneratedParserUtilBase.java#L871

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to do this. Since overriding makes no sense in a static context and instead just adds confusion. It also seems to be illegal in Kotlin https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html probably for this very reason.

Comment: Notice that `ParserUtil`'s `adapt_builder_` does not in fact override `GeneratedParserUtilBase`'s. Just call it something else. Unless there's some sort of reflection depending on the name (which it could be, I have no idea), it should be fine.

Comment: Overriding a static member is impossible in Java, as well as Kotlin. Your so-called "working example" is wrong, you can verify by adding an `@Override` annotation.

Comment: This question is not that bad, why do you downvote it? He's right, in Java it's possible to "hide" a static method by providing the same signature in subclasses, this is perfectly legal!

Comment: @s1m0nw1 well, hiding isn't overriding, the question is why the error `m1 overrides nothing` occurs.

Comment: Yeah that’s wording...

Comment: @Mango, question is how to redefine/override static method. Obviously, I need change class behaviour, rather than academically get to know that static class cannot be _overriden_.

Comment: @dimcha well... Kotlin doesn't _have_ static methods. That's probably where your problem is _conceptually_. Make a `companion object`. I've posted an answer.

Comment: As others have stated, your are NOT overriding the method. Try calling 'super' in your 'overridden' method. These methods are part of the class, and are always part of the class. As others have said, you're merely 'hiding' the other implementation. This is why people are down-voting it. Static methods are utilities methods, and aren't composed or overridden.

Answer (score 0):

You are override a static method and overriding depends on having an instance of a class.

```
public class BaseOne {
    public void m1() {}
}
```

Comment: Sure, if I remove `static` all ok. But I asked about `static` case. I have wrote update to question with working java example.

Comment: @dimcha In your java example it uses hiding methods instead of overriding https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html